# Is it possible to use an array as a map key in java?

Tags: java

```
Map<Integer[], Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer[], Integer>();
```

I am trying to make a map with two ints in an array as the key and a different int as the value. The arrays will all be unique. However, I keep getting a java.lang.classcastexception error. any advice?

Comment: TreeMap needs its keys to be Comparable. Or you need to provide a Comparator. The error message of the exception should tell you that. Have you read it? Have you read the javadoc of TreeMap?

Comment: Or use HashMap, which does not require Comparable keys. Note that an array will be considered equal only to itself, not to other arrays with the same content.

Comment: Write your own object class to use as the key.  That way, your object class can implement Comparable.

Comment: thanks guys. switched to hash map! works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: As **Thomas** mentioned, you can pass a custom `Comparator` to a `TreeMap`. So your original code can be work with a little modification:

```
Map<Integer[], Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer[], Integer>(new IntegerWordComparator());
```

In this case, `IntegerWordComparator` will be something similar to `IntegerWord` (see below), but as an implementation of the `Comparator` interface:

```
public class IntegerWordComparator implements Comparator<Integer[]> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer[] iw1, Integer[] iw2) {
        int commonLength = Math.min(iw1.length, iw2.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < commonLength; i++) {
            if (iw1[i] > iw2[i]) {
                return 1;
            } else if (iw1[i] < iw2[i]) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        if (iw1.length > iw2.length) {
            return 1;
        } else if (iw1.length < iw2.length) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

---

## Original answer

Use `List` instead of array, and `HashMap` instead of `TreeMap`:

```
Map<List<Integer>, Integer> map = new HashMap<List<Integer>, Integer>();

// add three items two of which are the same
map.put(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}), 1);
map.put(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{3, 4, 7}), 2);
map.put(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}), 4);

// print the size
System.out.println(map.size()); // 2
```

If you want to ignore the order, then use `Set` as key.

If you really want to use `TreeMap` and you want to compare your arrays lexicographically, then you can write your own class and use it as a key. Here is an example:

```
public class IntegerWord implements Comparable<IntegerWord> {

    protected final Integer[] integers;

    public IntegerWord(Integer... integers) {
        this.integers = integers;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(IntegerWord other) {
        int commonLength = Math.min(integers.length, other.integers.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < commonLength; i++) {
            if (integers[i] > other.integers[i]) {
                return 1;
            } else if (integers[i] < other.integers[i]) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        if (integers.length > other.integers.length) {
            return 1;
        } else if (integers.length < other.integers.length) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other instanceof IntegerWord) {
            return (compareTo((IntegerWord)other) == 0);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.asList(integers).toString();
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
Map<IntegerWord, Integer> map = new TreeMap<IntegerWord, Integer>();
map.put(new IntegerWord(2, 5), 11);
map.put(new IntegerWord(1, 2, 3), 22);
map.put(new IntegerWord(1, 2, 3, 4), 33);
map.put(new IntegerWord(1, 2, 3), 44); // 1, 2, 3 again!
map.put(new IntegerWord(3, 9, 3, 4), 55);
map.put(new IntegerWord(0, 1), 66);
map.put(new IntegerWord(), 77); // will be the first!
System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: No need to write your own array wrapper: you can pass a `Comparator` to a `TreeMap`.

Answer (score 1):

Array doesnt implement equals() and hashCode(), so you if you use array as key, you can get value back only with exact same array.

```
Integer[] key1 = {1, 2, 3};
Integer[] key2 = {1, 2, 3};
System.out.println(key1.equals(key2)); //false
System.out.println(key1.hashCode() == key2.hashCode()); //false

Map<Integer[], String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(key1, "value");
System.out.println(map.get(key1)); //value
System.out.println(map.get(key2)); //null
```

Better to create wrapper like this:

```
class IntArrayKey {
    Integer[] array;

    public IntArrayKey(Integer... array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        IntArrayKey that = (IntArrayKey) o;
        return Arrays.equals(array, that.array);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(array);
    }
}
```

P.S. For using with TreeMap you can implement Comparable

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example, using HashMap rather than TreeMap.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer[], Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer[], Integer>();
    Integer[] array1 = {1, 2, 3};
    Integer[] array2 = {4, 5, 6};

    map.put(array1, 42);
    map.put(array2,  -1000);
    System.out.println("array1: "+map.get(array1));
  }
}
```